# Azure DocumentDB | Connection Strings missing on Settings

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

I've noticed that connection strings link is missing on settings section in Azure Portal.

I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-connect-mongodb-account) in order to use .NET mongodb driver to work with Azure DocumentDB.

Look at the image below(from the tutorial)
[image]

And in my azure portal it does not show the connection strings.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `Connection Strings` option appears when you configure a database with MongoDB compatibility (which you must choose when creating your new database:

[image: mongo compat enable]

Once you do this, you'll then have the `Connection String` option:

[image: mongo connection string]

With databases where you have not enabled MongoDB compatibility, you're correct that the connection info appears under `Keys`:

[image: DocumentDB keys]

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to build my connection string by comparing the tutorial screen shots and the information that is on my Azure Portal. I've navigate to **Keys** link, and used the **Primary Key** as **Password** but that's not very obvious since the word may confuse the reader.

Also the **Port 10250** that is shown in the tutorial is not mentioned anywhere in the Azure Portal, I've just tried it and it worked.

It makes me believe that connection strings link is missing on purpose and not due a bug.

For those who are looking for the **Connection Strings** link to complete the tutorial here's what I did.

```
string endpoint = "bi4all-nosql"; //Your DocumentDB Name
string password ="********"; //Primary Key
string ConnectionString = $"mongodb://{endpoint}:{password}@{endpoint}.documents.azure.com:10250/?ssl=true";

MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(ConnectionString));
settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings
            {
                EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
            };
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

Comment: It's not a bug and not missing: If you don't enable MongoDB compat when creating your database, then the connection string isn't shown, and info is only found in Keys. See my answer for further explanation. You don't have to create your own connection string.